# Command for MSSQL DB backup?

Tags: mysql, php

What's the command I should use in order to get a backup of MSSQL DB saved in an sql file (command by PHP)? I need data from my old DB saved and then imported into MySQL

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129/how-to-export-data-from-sql-server-2005-to-mysql has the answer to your question

Answer (score 1):

- Open SQL Server Management Studio.
- Start backup dialog.
- At the end do not press "ok" but the "to script" button on top.

THEN:

- Use books online to read up on all the featuers.

Hint: What you want makes no sense. You can make a backup, but why you think MySWQL can handle SQL Server internal backup format? What you want is a data dump, but a backup is sql server storage format speciific.